# Android GestureOverlayView parameters

Tags: android, gesture

I started experimenting with Custom Gestures and the GestureOverlayView and noticed a few variables where I am not sure what they are for and what range of values can and should be assigned, the docs seem to be somewhat vague on those:

```
//Minimum curve angle a stroke must contain before it is recognized as a gesture. 
android:gestureStrokeAngleThreshold
```

> I assumed this is in degrees and when I add "25" here, a sharp edge must be contained in the gesture, but actually it still is detected ifI draw a circle or a perfect square.

```
//Minimum length of a stroke before it is recognized as a gesture. 
android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold
```

> Is this in dp ? Because it seems like on smaller screens it is harder to trigger the gesture...

```
//Squareness threshold of a stroke before it is recognized as a gesture. 
android:gestureStrokeSquarenessThreshold
```

> what is this?

**EDIT:**

Ok I just realized that every prediction has a score value, which should be used to find out if the gesture performed actually meets the requirements, so I added a check if the prediction's score is greater than 1.

Still I am curious what those variables in GestureOverlayView are doing, so enlighten me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gestureStrokeLengthThreshold definitely is not density independent but apparently uses pixels. If you want to set a density independent threshold you can calculate the gestureStrokeLengthThreshold at runtime, like that:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float normalizedScreenSize = (metrics.heightPixels + metrics.widthPixels) / 2.0f;
    return normalizedScreenSize * GESTURE_LENGTH_THRESHOLD;
```

GESTURE_LENGTH_THRESHOLD would be a value representing how long the gesture should be. A value of 1.0 would roughly be the size of the screen (averaged from screen width and height)

Still I am interested in what those other variables in GestureOverlayView do, so if you know more - enlighten me :)